# Can't open webpage when using Selenium Chromdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm having issues opening a webpage when using Selenium Chromedriver for Python on Windows 11.
I've installed the latest version of Selenium, the version of Chromedriver and Chrome start with the same numbers so they should be compatible and I added the PATH, so when I check `chromedriver` on cmd it returns:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.41 (976ef12907ef9b413c2d929c043307b415d27b9e-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#737}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

But when I open the .py file on cmd with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

The Chrome web page only opens for an instant and then it shuts and the cmd returns this message:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62215/devtools/browser/97b9072c-b1fd-4ace-9f82-8b31bf2fbf3c
```

I updated Selenium and made sure it was running. Same thing with chromedriver.

I expect to find a solution and be able to open a webpage when running that line of code.